# GraphQL : Error while adding computed fields

Tags: postgresql, graphql, psql, hasura, computed-field

I am trying to add a computed field to my graphql table "user" in schema "abc" using the hasura API but receiving the following error :

```
Saving computed field failed
in table "abc.user": in computed field "full_name": the computed field "full_name" 
cannot be added to table "abc.user" because the function "abc.fullname" is 
of type VOLATILE; cannot be added as a computed field
```

The function is added correctly :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abc.fullname(userrow abc.user)
    RETURNS TEXT AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT userrow.first_name || ' ' || userrow.last_name;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am able to select the function "fullname" from the dropdown but getting an error on adding computed field. Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is trying to tell you. You need to explicitly declare the function as `immutable` so it can be used in the definition of the computed column:

```
create or replace function abc.fullname(userrow abc.user)
returns text immutable as $$
begin
    select userrow.first_name || ' ' || userrow.last_name;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```